# Datatable aoColumnDefs not loading server side data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using datatable to show the records in table  and calling ajax for getting response from server side , it is working fine with out "success" call back property in Ajax, if i add "success" call back functionality ,
aoColumnDefs not loading the server side data , Can any one advise what is the cause of this issue or am i missing something?

Please refer the given below sample code .

```
$('#country').dataTable({
                "autoWidth": true,
                "processing": true,
                "scrollY" : 450,
                "language": {
                    "zeroRecords": "",
                    "emptyTable":  "No Data Available",
                    "loadingRecords": "",
                    "processing":     "Processing  ",
                },

            "ajax": {
                "url": serviceURL,
                "type": "POST",
                "contentType": 'application/json',
                "dataType":"json",
                "data" : function ( d ) {
                        return JSON.stringify(request)
                        },
                "success": function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
       //       Based on the server side response i am trying to show the response that is result data or exception message.
            }                           
            },
            "aoColumnDefs" : [  {
                    "mData": "location",
                    "sWidth": "15%",
                    "title": column1Title,

                },{
                        "mData": "date",
                }       

            ]});
```

My objective is based on the server side response ,i want to show the result table or exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `success` property, it's used internally by jQuery DataTables, see [this note](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object):

> `success` - Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server use `ajax.dataSrc`, or use `ajax` as a function.

To handle Ajax error, you can either use `ajax` as a function or handle [`xhr`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event. Event handler should be attached **before** DataTables initialization.

For example:

```
$('#country')
    .on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
       if(json === null){
          // Ajax error
       }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your input , so will it help to  handle  the application exception ? For success json response aoColumnDefs load the data in datatable , i am focusing for failure json response , Please advise